# OpenVPN works locally but not publically

Tags: windows-vista, firewall, port-forwarding, arch-linux, openvpn

## Main Problem

I can get OpenVPN to work when I use all local IP addresses but when I try to connect the client to a public address, it doesn't work.

I'm following this guide: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html *(I from the beginning to the part where it tells you to start pinging.)*

Some questions:

- **Is my linux firewall misconfigured; is linux blocking incoming traffic on port 1194?**
- **Is my router misconconfigured; are ports not forwarding from 74.125.224.72:12345 to 10.0.0.55:1194?**
- **Is it something else completely?**

Please help.

### Here's what works (Completely Local Setup):

*OpenVPN Server (Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi) server.conf*:

```
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
secret static.key
```

*OpenVPN Client (32bit Vista Home Premium on HP DV9000)*:

```
remote 10.0.0.55 # Just a local address
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.1
secret static.key
```

How do I know it works?

1. I got a popup in my windows system tray telling me `client connected IP: 10.8.0.2`
2. The windows system tray icon went from red to yellow to green
3. I can ping both 10.8.0.1 and 10.8.0.2 from both the client and the server, and i get this output from "show status" on the windows client:

>

```
<date> OpenVPN 2.1.3 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Aug 20 2010
<date> IMPORTANT: OpenVPN's default port number is now 1194, based on an official port number assignment by IANA.  OpenVPN 2.0-beta16 and earlier used 5000 as the default port.
<date> NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
<date> TAP-WIN32 device [TAP] opened: \\.\Global\{1B553AA7-3CE3-4067-B414-5D86E9998017}.tap
<date> Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.255.252 on interface {1B553AA7-3CE3-4067-B414-5D86E9998017} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.1, lease-time: 31536000]
<date> Successful ARP Flush on interface [27] {1B553AA7-3CE3-4067-B414-5D86E9998017}
<date> UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
<date> UDPv4 link remote: 10.0.0.55:1194
<date> Peer Connection Initiated with 10.0.0.55:1194
<date> Initialization Sequence Completed
```

### Here's what doesn't work (Public IP destination):

*OpenVPN Server (Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi) server.conf*:

```
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
secret static.key
```

*OpenVPN Client (32bit Vista Home Premium on HP DV9000)*:

```
remote 74.125.224.72 12345 # My home's public address and desired port to forward (Changed for demonstration)
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.1
secret static.key
```

How do I know it doesn't work? Well:

1. The windows system tray icon went from red to yellow but stays yellow
2. I can ping 10.8.0.1 but not 10.8.0.2 on the server
3. I can ping 10.8.0.2 but not 10.8.0.1 on the client
4. Even though I am quite sure I enabled forwarding of udp port 74.125.224.72:12345 on my router, pointed to 10.0.0.55:1194, I can't verify that 74.125.224.72:12345 is open with this port scanner: http://www.canyouseeme.org/, (*Maybe it's my linux firewall but I don't know how to configure it*)
5. I get this output from "show status" on the windows client:

>

```
<date> OpenVPN 2.1.3 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Aug 20 2010
<date> NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
<date> TAP-WIN32 device [TAP] opened: \\.\Global\{1B553AA7-3CE3-4067-B414-5D86E9998017}.tap
<date> Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.255.252 on interface {1B553AA7-3CE3-4067-B414-5D86E9998017} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.1, lease-time: 31536000]
<date> Successful ARP Flush on interface [27] {1B553AA7-3CE3-4067-B414-5D86E9998017}
<date> UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
<date> UDPv4 link remote: 74.125.224.72:12345
```